# Eclipse changed all my comments and now everything can hardly read

Tags: eclipse

I have many classes created in eclipse and now everything is in a very odd format for the comments. I am typing it in Japanese. Now all my file comments become like this:

```
/** 繝励�ｼ繝ｫ縺ｫ蛻ｩ逕ｨ蜿ｯ*/
```

I don't get why. It was supposed to be readable and now all like this. I tried to change it to UTF-8 or any other type but to no avail. Please help me. All my comments took me days to months to make it.

Comment: Does in _Project > Properties: Resource_ changing the _Text file encoding_ to _Other: UTF-8_ fix your problem?

Comment: I tried that too but it wont work. I still dont know how it becomes like this.

Comment: This is because the file has been opened with a different text file encoding than it was written. If you tried to convert the file, data may have been lost. The text file encoding is only how the bytes have to be read as text and how the text has to be written as bytes. In Eclipse, the text file encoding can be specified on different levels: workspace, project, folder and file.

Comment: Is there a way to return it back to its previous state?

Comment: Try right clicking on the file in Package or Project Explorer and using 'Restore from Local History...' to see what older versions Eclipse has.

Comment: @kingkongmanoftheworldinchaos That depends on exactly what you did. If you have not converted the file, setting the correct text file encoding should be enough.

Comment: Thank you guys. Everything is not working so I will just recomment everything again.